# Rspec does not see my active record models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm pretty new to Rspec. I'm using Rails 6. I added the following gems for Rspec and ran the install command for rspec.

```
 gem 'rspec-rails'
 gem 'rexml'
```

I created a spec/models/post_spec.rb file that looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do

  it "doesn't create a post without a title" do
    Post.new(title: "", body: "weqwe").save
  end
end
```

When I run rspec I get the following error

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `post' for #<Post id: nil, title: "", body: "weqwe", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I played with the code and it breaks any time I try to do something with Active Record.

Also, if it helps, running rails test doesn't pick up any of my tests.

EDIT: Here's the full error

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/post_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: Post.create({title: "something", body: "something"})

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `post' for #<Post id: nil, title: "something", body: "something", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
# ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
# ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:4:in `block in <main>'
# ./spec/models/post_spec.rb:3:in `<main>'
# /Users/mymac/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
# /Users/mymac/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'


Finished in 0.00007 seconds (files took 6.23 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Comment: Did you create your test DB?

Comment: I ran rails db:create when I started my app. I think that created my test and development db. And I just tried rails db:test:prepare and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: "db:create" without setting the env creates the dev DB, not test, although iirc db:test:prepare should create the test db and earn if it's missing migrations. You should include the entire stack trace--the error indicates missing fields or a coding error.

Comment: I updated my post with the error.

Comment: What does the "posts" table look like? Is it called "posts"?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Found the error. In my model's validation I was validating a field :post, when my table doesn't have that column.

Comment: Great; glad you worked it out.

Comment: Unrelated, but please don't add answers to the question; if you feel it's of value to others you can self-answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem was I had this in my model validation. I don't have a post atribute on my post table

```
  validates :title, :post, presence: true
```